# Ordering take-out in Taiwan 带走 vs 外帶?

Tags: expressions

This may or may not be Taiwan specific, but on all the order cards the option for take-out is "外帶".

Is this a Taiwanese vs Chinese Mandarin difference, or is this just a noun vs verb difference?

ie. If I'm ordering food to go, should I say "我想要____带走" or "我想要____外帶"?

Thanks!

Comment: A: 您要点什么？ **在这吃** / **堂吃** 还是 **带走** / **外带** / **打包** ？
B: 我要一份鸡翅 **带走** / **打包** 。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most of China, you can say 外卖 or 打包. But the wording changes as where you are, as Williej said, in Taiwan or Fujian you say 外带, in North East China you say 带走.

Answer (score 0):

In Taiwan "外帶" is used. It usually means to order something to-go. The difference between the two is mostly location. If you were in China, you might say the latter.

Answer (score 0):

both are well understood and they are interchangeable. it really doesn't matter in that sense.